Where is the RegEx syntax specification of Swift?
Where is the RegEx syntax specification of Swift? Like what character classes are supported, what matching constructs are supported, etc.?
In the official documentation I only see what is supported programmatically but usually you don't code RegEx's, usually you write them in RegEx syntax (/.../) and here pretty much every programming language on earth has its own variant of that syntax (usually a subset of PCRE), so there should be a documentation describing what syntax elements are supported (and thus implicitly what elements are not).
Background
There are only three officially standardized types of Regular Expression syntaxes:

Simple Regular Expressions (SRE)
Basic Regular Expressions (BRE)
Extended Regular Expressions (ERE)

As for the first one, forget that I even mentioned it, it has been deprecated a long time ago. Those three syntax where standardized by the IEEE as part of the POSIX standard in 1992 (with the release of POSIX.2). That means there is an official documentation that describes exactly what tokens do exist and how the matching process works in regard to those tokens.
When Perl was released in 1987 no final RegEx standard existed, so Perl created its own standard, which is today known as Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE).
Today the C API (regex.h) still only supports BRE and ERE (BRE is the default). Most modern programming languages rather prefer PCRE, yet none of them supports the full feature set that Perl supports, they all only support a subset of PCRE and this subset varies from language to language.
E.g. to match a digit in ERE, you'd use [[:digit:]] and to match any non-digit you'd use [^[:digit:]], to match a digit in PCRE you'd use \d and to match a non-digit you'd use \D (yet Perl also supports the ERE syntax). Yet not all languages support all PRCE classes.
Swift does support \d and \w but does it also support \N? PHP does. Python, Go, Java, .NET, and Rust do not. You shouldn't have to guess and find out by trial and error, every language should have a documentation of its supported RegEx syntax.
To name a few:
Perl: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre 
PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php 
Python: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html
How would I know that Swift knows \d and \D, \w and \W but not \N? What about look-ahead and look-back? What about different kind of capture groups?
I found a syntax description in the documentation for NSRegularExpression, which you can use in Swift as well on macOS but only thanks to the Foundation framework. That's not the native RegEx engine built into the Swift language.
Here's the documentation for NSRegularExpression: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression 
(if you scroll down a bit, you will see the full syntax is listed there in tables)
BTW, NSRegularExpression is based on the ICU's regular expression engine, which is just another PRCE subset but optimized for Unicode processing (Perl RegEx has Unicode support but may not handle all Unicode data always correctly or as expected). Yet Swift states that it explicitly is not based on the ICU engine as the way how this engine thinks about the string data type is fundamentally incompatible to how strings are implemented in Swift, so there would be a huge overhead converting strings back and forth.

This reads too much like a external resource request, which is not on-topic for Stack Overflow. I think this is salvageable though, with some edits.

@Sweeper Feel free to post the documentation here instead or provide an answer like "Swift RegEx is based on ...<whatever standard, library or programming language implementation>"

Alternatively I can just make 1000 questions on SO and just ask "Dose Swift RegEx support ..." followed by each PRCE character class, each PCRE capture group, each PRCE token, each PRCE look-wherever feature, etc. if you think that is more beneficial for any developer out there; but I strongly doubt that.

Aha, it's this other markdown file.

Your point notwithstanding (the lack of an obvious document outlining the supported regex), FWIW, if you attempt to use look-behind in Swift Regex, i.e., let regex = /(?<=un)cola/), it gives you a compile-time warning: “Cannot parse regular expression: lookbehind is not currently supported”. While I was disappointed this wasn't supported, I was pleasantly surprised to see real-time reporting of the issue (rather than silently failing or replying on some runtime behaviors to discover the problem). I'd suggest you post a bug with Feedback assistant.

Can I answer my own question?, and How to answer, which should explain that you should not write the answer in the question.

@Luuk I couldn't answer my own question because the question was closed and I cannot answer a closed question, not even my own one.

Thanks and credits go to Sweeper, who found the following information and shared a link to it in a comment:

Syntax
We propose accepting a syntactic "superset" of the following existing regular expression engines:

PCRE 2, an "industry standard" and a rough superset of Perl, Python, etc.
Oniguruma, a modern engine with additional features.
ICU, used by NSRegularExpression, a Unicode-focused engine.
.NET, which adds delimiter-balancing and some interesting minor details around conditional patterns.

To our knowledge, all other popular regex engines support a subset of the above syntaxes.

Source: Regex Syntax and Run-time Construction
So, as expected, Swift has its own syntax mix that is incompatible with any other programming language and borrows features from various languages and existing RegEx implementations.
The site also goes into more detail about which RegEx constructs are currently supported. You can expect most standard PCRE expressions to work, but be careful with the more fancy stuff (e.g. look behind is not supported as Rob has pointed out in a comment to the question).
